# Git says I deleted photos that I put inside a new folder?

Tags: git

I added a folder to my local repo to hold all of the photos I am using in the project. (Just to clean things up as they used to just be mixed in with the html files etc) Then, I moved all of the photos into the folder and adjusted my code to find the photos. I did a "git status" and it says I deleted those photos, but it also found the new folder (I did a "git  add"  for the new folder--I assume it also knows the contents?) Before I do a "git rm" for the ones it says I deleted, I wanted to make sure it now sees the photos inside the folder that I added. I'm new to this, hopefully I explained it well enough.  Thanks!!

Comment: Did you use "git mv" to move the files?

Comment: no I didnt realize I had to. Im just learning this stuff. Thank You I learned somethig today!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do `git add -u .`, and then run `git status` which should show that the files were moved. Give that a try?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Git is detecting that you have moved those files.

Simply do this:

```
git add -u
git commit -m "moved photos"
```

The -u flag is a shortcut for doing all the "git mv" statements for moving files around.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I appreciate it so much!! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

git doesn't really understand file moves; it tracks the files by their paths, so a file that has been moved within a repository is seen as 1 deleted file and 1 new file. From your description, you handled this correctly.

As others have said: do `git add -u` and you can safely commit the changes.